# why am getting Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] error?

Tags: angularjs

I am getting Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

[getting this as error reference](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/docs/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.8%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DmyCountrollers%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.5.8%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DmyCountrollers%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A412%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A25%253A99%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520b%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A142)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A385%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A471%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520q%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A355)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A319)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A488%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520q%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A355)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A319)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:6:412%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:40:222%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:7:355)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:39:319)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:39:488%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:7:355)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:39:319)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20cb%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:43:336)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:20:390)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Bc%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:21:179)

while I run the 'SearchCountroller' controller function in angular js.

> angular js version v1.5.8

#### app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [

'ngRoute',

'myCountrollers'

]);



myApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){

$routeProvider

.when('/',{

templateUrl: 'js/portal/search.html',

controller:'SearchCountroller'

});

}]);
```

#### controller.js

```
 var myCountrollers = angular.module(myCountrollers, []);



myCountrollers.controller('SearchCountroller', function MyController($scope,$http) {

$http.get('js/data.json').then(function(response) {

$scope.artists = response.data;

$scope.myartistOrder = 'name';

});

});
```

#### index.html

```
<!-- script -->
<script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller.js"></script>

<body class="bg-secondary" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCountrollers">
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi @HViji. I suggest you post the actual error listing you got as well as the link to the theoretical definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`angular.module` gets name parameter as string:

```
var myCountrollers = angular.module('myCountrollers', []);
```

Moreover, you need to use controller's name in your template (instead of module name):

```
<body class="bg-secondary" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SearchCountroller">
```